# Is it natural and correct to say "I can't feel my fingerst" meaning my fingers are numb?

Tags: verbs, collocations, verb-usage

Is it natural and correct to say *I can't feel my fingerst* meaning my fingers are numb? For example:

> I guess I had better go to the doctor. I can't feel my fingers at all.

If it doesn't sound right, what would be the most natural way to communicate the meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I can't feel my fingers* is completely natural and correct, with or without the final *at all*.

We might equally say, *My fingers have gone numb.*

If a doctor asked, "Can you feel your hand?" we might say simply, *My fingers are numb*. It sounds slightly calmer and more matter-of-fact than the sentences above.